Was Viktor suggesting that Andrey Pavlovich bribe people to vote for him?
In chapter 11 of Penguin Lost, Viktor has the following discussion with Andrey Pavlovich about his political campaign:

"Well, we'll see, though I get the point. Now let's recap. First, what to promise to the poor. Nobody shells out money in the streets - any fool can see that."
"But they do, before an election, to secure votes. At least 10 hryvanas a head."
Andrey Pavlovich looked surprised.

What did Viktor mean by this? Was he proposing that Andrey Pavlovich literally bribe people to vote for him, or is there a different meaning here? If so, how common would that have been? And why was Andrey Pavlovich surprised by the proposal?

In short, the answer is "Yes".
Penguin Lost was first published in 2005, a period when Ukranian elections were notably corrupt. The 2004 presidential election, for example, was so flawed that, as wikipedia notes, "The European Union made it clear that they would not recognize the election results. All 25 member countries summoned their ambassadors from Ukraine in order to register a sharp protest against what was seen as election fraud."
A work by NCEER (National Council for Eurasian and East European Research) produced a study of the methods by which electoral fraud was commonly effected in Ukraine, and one of them was indeed "Bribing/buying the votes". The method described in the question probably falls under:

Enforceable bribing: It is interesting that the vote can be bought in exchange of the proof of the voting which has been made possible
because of the modern technologies.  For example, a person votes,
takes picture of the ballot, comes out of the precinct, shows the
picture to the buyer and receives his reward.  Obviously, one cannot
buy votes everywhere (you need to have rather impossible sum of
money), as a result only certain (the most contentious) precincts are
targeted.

The practice was so commonplace that people were able to quote going-rates for their votes:

It is quite notable that many interviewees were able to provide the
cost of average bribe in case of buying a vote (50-100-150-200 HRV)...
Just as an average American is able to recite the price of the
gasoline or cost of milk or eggs in a grocery store, those
interviewees were able to produce the knowledge about those hidden or
supposedly non-existing transactions.

This is corroborated by a poll carried out by the Democratic Initiatives Foundation and the Ukrainian Sociology Service in 2009, which while carrying the ostensibly positive message that "Most Ukrainians not planning to sell their votes in presidential election" nonetheless found that a sizeable minorty were willing to sell their votes:

13% expressed readiness to take the funds if they initially planned to
vote for their presidential candidate, and 5.8% said they were ready
to sell their votes if the sum suited them. Only 1.9% of respondents
are ready to sell their votes for any presidential candidates and for
any funds, with 6.6% undecided.

A detailed breakdown of the pricing was provided:

0.6% of voters are ready to sell their votes in the election for Hr 50, 1.1% for Hr 51-100, 2.3% for Hr 101-200, 3.6% for Hr 201-300, 3.4%
for Hr 301-500, and 12.9% for over Hr 500.

It is tricky to compare the hryvana over time due to the large swings in its value, but 10 hryvanas in 2004 seems roughly compatible with the price of buying a vote in 2009.
